# Informative vs unique generated ID in REST API

Tags: rest

Designing a RESTful API. I have two ways of identifying resources (person data). Either by the unique ID generated by the database, or by a social security number (SSN), entered for each person. The SSN is supposedly unique, though can be changed.

Using the ID would be most convenient for me, since it is guaranteed to be unique, and does not change. Hence the URL for the resource, also always stays the same:

```
GET /persons/12

{
  "name": Morgan
  "ssn": "840212-3312"
}
```

The argument for using SSN, is that it is more informative and understandable by API clients. SSN is also used more in surrounding systems:

```
GET /persons/840212-3321

{
  "name": Morgan
  "id": "12"
}
```

So the question is: Should I go with the first approach, and avoid some implementation headaches where the SSN may change. And maybe provide some helper method that converts from SSN to ID?

Or go with the second approach. Providing a more informative API. Though having to deal with some not so RESTful strangeness where URL:s might change due to SSN changes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

URL design is a personal choice. But to give you some more examples which differ from those Ray has already provided, I will give you some of my own.

I have a user account resource and allow access via both URIs:

```
/users/12
```

and

```
/users/morgan
```

where the numerical value is an auto_incremented ID, and the alphabetic value is a unique username on the system specified by the user. these resources are uncachable so I do not bother about canonicalisation, however the `/users` page links to the alphabetic forms.

No other resources on my system have two unique fields, so are referred to by IDs, `/jobs/123`, `/quotations/456`.

As you can see, I prefer plural URI segments ;-)
I think of "job 123" as being from the "jobs" collection, so it seems logical to have a "jobs" resource, with subresources for each job.

You do not need to have a separate `/search/` area for performing searches, I think it would be cleaner to apply your search criteria to the collection resource directly:

```
/people?ssn=123456-7890  (people with SSN matching/containing "123456-7890")
/people?name=morgan      (people who's name is/contains "Morgan")
```

I have something similar, but use only the first letter as a filter:

```
/sites?alpha=f
```

Lists all sites beginning with F. You can think of it as a filter, or as a search criteria, those terms are just different sides of the same coin.

Comment: I agree /search/ isn't necessary in the url and that leaving it off is cleaner.  I  added it just for clarity in my example as it's neither good nor bad.  I think plural and singular is one of those religious things along the lines of whether you should name your DB tables single or plural, but it's definitely just preference.

Comment: Hmmm... No love for our insight.  Gonna +1 you for having a brain.

Comment: @Ray I took over an extant project and the database tables were already named in the plural. When I remodelled the URI space from (for example) `/viewopenjobs.php` to `/jobs?status=open` I just truncated the file names, so they ended up plural too.

Comment: Would you allow modifying the resource by both URL:s, eg `PUT /users/12` and `PUT /users/morgan`? My guess is that the username, may be changed? Hence also the second URL changes. Problem if API clients only keep the usename as reference?

Comment: They both point to the same PHP script, so yes, either will work. The username cannot be changed (by company policy) so that is why I consider it permissible to use it as part of the URL. Otherwise I would not.

Answer (score 3):

Good to see someone taking time to think about their Resource urls!

I would make a Url with the unique id to provide resource to a single user.  Like:

```
http://api.mysite.com/person/12/
```

Where 12 is your unique ID.  Note that I also prefer the singular 'person'....

Regardless, the url should return:

```
{
  "ssn":  "840212-3312"
  "name": "Morgan"
  "id": "12"
}
```

However, I would also create a general search URL that returns a list of users that match the parameters (either a json array or whatever format you need).  You can specify search parameters as get params like this:

```
 http://api.mysite.com/person/search/?ssn=840212-3312
```

Or

```
 http://api.mysite.com/person/search/?name=Morgan
```

These would return something like this for a single search hit--note it's an array, not a single item like the unique id url that points directly to a single user.

```
[{
  "ssn":  "840212-3312"
  "name": "Morgan"
  "id": "12"
}]
```

This search could then be later augmented for other search criteria.  You might only return the unique id's via the search Url--you could always make a request to the unique id url once you've got it from the search...

Comment: Related to `/search/` is your ending of resource paths with a slash. IMHO it is better to make URLs as short as possible, to aid human reading, memorability and even rote copying onto paper. Ending the URL with a trailing slash adds no benefit for the developer, nor for the user, so I would suggest eliminating it. Also, do you use `/person/` as the collection resource, or would that be `/people/`? If the latter, why do you have both singular and plural, and why use two "hierarchies" in your URI space?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use neither. Generate resource IDs that are unique both to a single user of your API and across all other resources (including other users' resources).

Using the unique database ID is not ideal for a couple of reasons. First, API resources and database records won't necessarily always be 1-to-1 even if you have designed it that way today. Second, you might change to a different data store that would generate different format unique ids.

Also, it is good practice to separate out the ID from other resource properties, such as SSN (as an aside I hope you are storing SSN in a very secure manner, but that's another topic). If for whatever reason an SSN changed, more than one API resource was associated with the same SSN, or you decide that piece of data is not needed someday, you don't want to have to change the ID.

One pattern is to prepend the unique ID with a few characters that indicate the resource type. For example if User is a resource type in you API, a generated unique ID would be something like `USR56382`.

Answer (score 0):

RESTful API is an architectural style which emphasizes on resource centric design approach.

In my opinion, I would keep the resources as plural and noun format.

Every resource, for example, customers has following uniform interfaces

POST /customers - for creating a resource instance
PUT  /customers/{customerId} - for updating a particular instance
GET  /customers - is for search customers. So @Ray, search is not required to be part of URI itself. Any filter or query parameters that need to be supported should be there itself.
GET /customers/{customerId} - to retrieve a particular instance of customer
DELETE /customers/{customerId} to delete a particular instance

The reason why plural, it is because it behaves as a factory. For example, when u r trying to create a new instance of a resource, the instance does not exist and therefore, it cannot be on the self instance. Hence, singularity is not used.
It also goes hand-in-hand for search/inquiry, where you do not know or hold the actual instance of resource. Hence, the plural form is much recommended.

Now, the question is what to use for a resource id - a database primary key, a generated identifier, or an encrypted token.

In my opinion, database primary keys should not be exposed. Resource identifier should not be designed 1-1 with DB primary key. But, it happens a lot. A generated UUID based key is much more recommended to avoid any sequential follow-through attack but world is not ideal always.

Coming back to token or an encrypted token, is a recommended approach for sensitive APIs, and where data exchange is performed between two separate applications. If we are using it, the encryption/decryption should be solely at the API end. That means, the encrypted keys for sub-resources should be returned as part of parent API response, otherwise it defeats the purpose.